# external reference to third-party library (Jar) inside another Jar without wrap the second inside the first

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I'm writing a small fragment of code that aims at using AppleScriptEngine in order to communicate with Growl. I would obtain a jar file called MyApplication.jar with all my classes but I need to refer AppleScriptEngine.jar (developed by Apple and stored in /System/Library/Java/Extension)... Here the problem: AppleScriptEngine.jar is present in each Os x distribution so I would like refer to it inside MyApplication.jar MANIFEST.MF without adding AppleScriptEngine.jar inside my .jar file. This basically for two reasons: first of all AppleScriptEngine is a proprietary file of Apple, second I hope there is a way to refer an existing file inside the file system. I read a lot about the right composition of a jar file and in each example I found there is the external jar file packaged inside the coder's jar file. 
I tryed to modify the class-path attribute inside my MANIFEST in order to point directly to the AppleScriptEngine.jar in this way:

**Manifest-Version: 1.0**

**Rsrc-Class-Path: ./**

**Class-Path: /System/Library/Java/Extensions/AppleScriptEngine.jar**

**Rsrc-Main-Class: core.MyApplicationLauncher**

**Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader**

Rsrc-Class-Path should be the local reference inside my jar, but giving the absolute path to Class-Path I sholud be able to refer to  each file  inside my system. Maybe there is something wrong in the way I define the path, or maybe I can refer only files that are nested inside my jar.   Inside eclipse obviously all works fine because it has references to JRE System Library wich contains AppleScriptEngine.jar too. So, maybe there is a way to refer directly to JRE System Library inside my MANIFEST file. I wasn't able to find  the answer after many hours of surfing.Has anyone an idea to overcome that impasse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find the solution after a lot of trials and errors. My mistake was try to add the absolute path of `AppleScriptEngine.jar` as attribute to `Class-Path`; instead the right solution is to add as attribute of `Class-Path` only the absolute path of the folder that contains the Jar file we are interested in (the external one) and then add the name of that Jar file as value of `Rsrc-Class-Path`. I believe this is the right way to refer externals libraries in each case in which the file is already located in the file system. Here my `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ AppleScriptEngine.jar

Class-Path: . /System/Library/Java/Extensions/

Rsrc-Main-Class: core.NotifierLauncher

Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

NOTE that after `Class-Path:` there is a blank space before the dot and after the dot. This is because the blank space is the way used inside the `MANIFEST` file to separate different arguments. There isn't a friendly documentation about that argument